# Apply border only for first set of list evenafter mouseover

Tags: html, css

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li>first set<li>
     <ul>
       <li>second set</li>
       <li>second set</li>
     </ul>
  <li>first set<li>
  <li>first set<li>
</ul>
```

I have applied border-left for first set of list using

```
#menu li
{
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

However when mouseover first set, second set list showing border-left of 2px.
But i dont want any border-left for second set. How do i remove this 2px?.

I could remove 1px by using

```
#menu ul li
{
  border-left: 0px;
}
```

How i can remove another 1px border of second set ?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `#menu > li` in your CSS instead of `#menu li` to limit the border to the first set.

i.e.

```
#menu > li
{
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

**Update**

As per the fiddle posted by the OP - http://jsfiddle.net/DrJsr/3/ , the markup is:

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li>first set<li>
     <ul>
       <li>second set</li>
       <li>second set</li>
     </ul>
  <li>first set<li>
  <li>first set<li>
</ul>
```

There are a couple of problems above:

- Some of the LIs are not closed. This can lead some browsers to mistake it as the start of another li
- The UL for the second set is a direct child of the main UL - which is invalid in HTML - Ideally the second UL should be the child of one of the LIs inside the main UL

Now, regarding the border - it is actually working correctly indeed. If you inspect the UL for the second set using Firebug or Chrome, you'll see that the browser automatically adds an LI to wrap the UL for the second set, thereby automatically making the HTML valid.

i.e. your HTML automatically becomes:

```
<ul id="menu"> 
  <li>first set</li>
  <li> <!-- this is added by browser and this LI will have a left border since it falls under #menu > li -->
     <ul> 
       <li>second set</li> 
       <li>second set</li> 
     </ul> 
  </li>
  <li>first set</li>
  <li>first set</li>
</ul>
```

This new LI falls under `#menu > li` and renders a left border. If you check in Firebug, you'll see that the left border you are seeing is the one rendered for this new LI.

Comment: be careful as this is not supported in older browsers.

Comment: It's supported in everything except IE6. Nobody cares about IE6 unless it's specifically mentioned in the question.

Comment: Thanks for answer. but since 'second set' below 'first set', border still carrying when mouse over.

Comment: Thats strange. `#menu > li` ensures in all cases that the styles defined within apply to **only** direct children of `#menu` that are of type `LI`. Also, you are not testing in IE correct? On the otherhand `#menu li` applies to all `LI`'s under `#menu` - See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors

Comment: @techfoobar: Your comment before your last is incorrect (I advise deleting it). The child combinator is supported in IE7/8.

Comment: It is? My info was that only IE9 and later versions supported the > selector.. Tks for the info.

Comment: @techfoober, see http://jsfiddle.net/DrJsr/3/  its not working in any browser..thanks

Comment: @user832901 - It is actually working as expected. Pls see my edit.

Comment: thanks for the correction @techfoober ..but if you see http://jsfiddle.net/DrJsr/4/ border still appearing for second set..

Comment: That is because the first set li is expanding to accomodate the full second set ul. If you give a margin and a background color for the second set ul, youll be able to see it.

Comment: last anwser is what i was expecting,,,can u update css for that margin..thanks

Answer (score 0):

There different approach to fix your problem. Here are an examples.

1. Create a CSS rule that have a selector pointing to the second set of list to style the border.

   ```
   #menu li li {border-left:0;}
   ```
2. Much better way is to add a class or an id on your second set of list and create a CSS rule for it. If I assumed you've add class="sub-menu" on the second `<ul>` list, then add the following CSS rule.

   ```
   #menu ul.sub-menu li {border-left:0;}
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
#menu:first-child
{
border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```